# OOM issue android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

How to solve OOM issue in android . I have tried almost every things like scaling bitmap,inPurgeable in BitmapOption,releasing all resources etc. but still getting OOM issue.
This is basically in images taken by camera or any image i.e. larger then 1.5 mb. I have also images 15-20 mb size in my app.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i´m doing to avoid OOM errors, Using some of the code of the android training. This is in my class "ScaledFactor"

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    options.inPurgeable = true; // I aded this to the android training code, without this I still have OOM errors. so try using inPurgeable = true

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

In my Activity I use

```
            background = ScaledFactor.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.menu, screenheight, screenwidth); // screeenhieght is the output height , screenwidth is the output width
```

Then in the on destroy method, or after calling an other intent I use background.recycle();

I´m not using the hdpi, ldpi and so folders... I just use the drawable with large bitmaps, and do the scalling. this way you save some mb on the final apk file

The android training code is here for more info http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

C ya ! Hope this helps, I spent a hole day trying to figure this out and reading all the questions and answers in this forum. This is just the example of the background image but i have more than 20 images in my game all loaded this way but with smaller output size, and it works very smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Bitmap.recycle();` ?

It once solved my Out of Memory issue.